# Sorting through values php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with rows containing an ID and a value.

I randomly insert these values between the numbers 1 and 100 as I insert records, so an ID has a random value. I use a while loop to go through the records and print them to screen. However, the way I want it is if the current value of the row in the while loop is LESS than the next value, then break out of the loop. Basically what I am asking is how to refer to the next record of a database while in a while loop working with the current, simply to check a value in it.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$previousRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$previousRow['ID'] = -1;

while($currentRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($currentRow['ID'] > $previousRow['ID'])
         break;

    echo $previousRow['Value'];
    $previousRow = $currentRow;
}
```

Comment: I would rather initialize `$previousRow['ID']` with `0` or `-1`.

Comment: I rather meant: Do not fetch the first row but just initialize `$previousRow['ID']` with some value.

Comment: @Gumbo, but then `echo $previousRow['Value'];` won't work. So, it has to be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastRecord = Array();
foreach($records as $thisRecord){
    if($lastRecord['value'] < $thisRecord['value']){
        // do what you need to do here
    }
    $lastRecord = $thisRecord;
}
```

This way you always keep the previous value stored

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way round. Instead of breaking out based on the next element, just check *on the next element* based on the previous element (which you can simply store somewhere). I guess that the loop actually loops through the elements and does something; you can then just check the previous/current element *first* before doing anything and nobody will notice that you in fact loaded the next element.